# Resolver erros relacionados com apport-GTK, dkpg e Git

Tags: git

Eu estava usando o Git no Linux e ao remover um *branch* que não desejava mais usar, provavelmente removi outras coisas a mais.

Acabou dando erro no apport e no dkpg. Com relação ao Git, ele só deixa continuar no *branch* master. Ao mudar para outros *branchs*, o Head aponta para (no *branch*). Já usei `apt-get purge, remove, -f install`, mas o erro do apport acabou afetando a conclusão do `apt-get`, isto é, não deixa concluir a instalação ou remoção com êxito.

Comment: Se isto resolveu seu problema, você pode aceitar a sua própria resposta. Veja mais em [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente o problema não está relacionado ao git, foi apenas alguma coincidência com alguma instalação feita no computador. 
O problema do aport continua.
Contudo,o git funciona. O problema de (no branch) era: o branch que estava aparecendo fazia parte do repositório remoto, mas ainda não estava no computador. Faltava dar checkout nos branches restantes.